# Negative borders (css)

Tags: html, css

I know how to make a border with css that looks like this:

```
    ___________
  _/           \_
 /               \
|                 |
|                 |
```

But is there a possibility to make a border that looks like that:

```
|\_             _/|
|  \___________/  |
|                 |
|                 |
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not without other overlapping elements (or pseudo elements) or using images.

Comment: You could try fiddling with CSS box-shadow `inset`.

Comment: overlapping elements won't work, because my background is a radial-gradient, so i cant use this: http://jsfiddle.net/MU6H8/1/

Comment: I have a few examples using pseudo elements to cut edges : http://codepen.io/collection/KIkgz/ , most of them uses box-shadow to allow to see main background behind , you have this collection too http://codepen.io/collection/LbCzx/ I guess you may find lots of other examples via searching

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution using a pseudo element with a box-shadow:

```
div {
    background: orange;
    width: 400px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}

div:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 70px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 70px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 100px orange;
    clip: rect(0px, 400px, 100px, 0px);
}
```

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MU6H8/2/)

Answer (score 3):

oki :), so from my comment, example  and your fiddle , is this what you look for ?
http://jsfiddle.net/MU6H8/3/

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}
body > div {
    width: 400px;
    margin : 1em auto;
    padding-top:40px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
body>div:before {
    content :'';
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    height:40px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 200px 40px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 200px 40px;
    transition:background 0.5s;
    background: orange;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2000px purple
}
div div {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    position:relative;
    background:purple
}
body:hover> div:before {
    background:none;
}
body {
    background:url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/abstract);
}
```

Notice that you do not really need to use 2 div nested when pseudo element and padding do the job.

Comment: Works, but i accepted the other answer because it's a shorter code. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Felix no problem, what matters is that you add an answer that fits your needs :)