# Semi Circle with text in CSS like in picture?

Tags: css

[image]

As you can see in the image above it's a semi circle spanning the width of the page and contains the text `WATCH IT FIRST`. So after playing around for a long time with `border-radius` values I was not able to achieve this specific shape. I'm very tired and it didn't dawn on me that it isn't a perfect semi-cirlce. It's stretched and I have no idea how to achieve that look. Any help would be so, so very appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: I found many questions asking about semi-circles but not stretched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
div {
    background: transparent;
    width: 400px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 70px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}

div:after{
    content: "CONTENT GOES HERE";
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 70px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 70px;
    clip: rect(0px, 400px, 100px, 0px);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Source: [Negative borders (css)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22422767/negative-borders-css)

border-bottom-left-radius and border-bottom-right-radius is what you need. Simply put them to 50% or whatever your requirement, depending on your height to make it a perfect semi-circle.

I didn't really get your question, but I think this is what you're talking about.

Comment: Trying to use the `:after` pseudo class with `position: absolute` caused problems with responsiveness.

Comment: oh, sorry about that!

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about, actually your answer helped me find the solution. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

None of the current answers really worked for me because the red semi-circle was gonna be in a `div` and I kept having problems with it colliding with other children. But after tweaking Lorddirt's answer I was able to make it work.

```css
.red-banner {
    background: #dc3545;
    color: white;

    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 120px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 120px;

    font-size: 3.2rem;

    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="bg-white text-center">
    <div class="red-banner">WATCH IT FIRST</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```